# Hashing and Dehasing

Tags: java, encryption, hash, cryptography, rsa

So, I'm attempting to write a cryptography method that uses a hash that both the sender and the receiver know. I'm confused as to how to dehash a message.

For example, the sender sends a the message

M: 50 and hashes it

So 50 % 30 = 20.

H = 30

So after hashing, the resulting message would be 30.

How would the receiver be able to dehash the message to receive the original with knowing the hash?

There's no code or anything. Just an important concept that I wish to grasp.

EDIT: So, I have a general understanding of encryption and decryption. For the sake of understanding. How would I get the original message using RSA?

For for example,

Sender Private Key: 55,27
Sender Public Key: 55,3

Receiver Private Key: 35,29
Receiver Public Key: 35, 5

Is this possible?

Comment: There is no such thing as "dehashing".

Comment: That makes sense. To my understanding, I can retrieve the original message via encryption/decryption.

Comment: If you want to use Java to encrypt / decrypt, I have a few [examples](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/). If you want to know how RSA works, you will need to search and read some more (there are plenty of articles) and ask specific question when stucked

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is encrypting and decrypting. Hashing is a one way function which usually loses information making it impossible to recreate the original message.

> Is there any way to receive the original message after hashing through encryption?

When you use encryption, you create some bytes which look random and can look like a long hash value. The difference is that the data can be decrypted back to the original information, whereas with hashing this is designed to be as hard as possible.

> If so, which encryption/decryption method do I use?

The key decision to make is whether you want symmetric or asymmetric encryption.  Symmetric is faster but requires the key for decryption be the same as encryption i.e. both the point of encryption and decryption needs to be secure.  If you use asymmetric encryption, you can allow one end to either decrypt or encrypt but not both. i.e. only one end needs to be secure.

Comment: Is there any way to receive the original message after hashing through encryption? If so, which encryption/decryption method do I use?

Comment: @Granzo You have a basic misunderstanding around hashing versus encryption.  "Hashing through encryption" and "dehashing" are both nonsensical phrases.  I suggest you do some research first and come back.